# How to return a buffer address in C

Tags: c, microcontroller

I'm trying to create a function that creates an string in RAM of a 16 bit microcontroller.
The function prototype is like this

```
char CID_Str[12] GetContactID(char Qual,long Event,char Partition,char Zone);
```

The function should return a little string created with the input parameters.

I never do it a function like this before.
I don't need help with the code inside the function.
I need to know how should I declare the returning parameter (Buffer) because the CCS compiler doesn't like that prototype.

Comment: `char *GetContactID(char Qual,long Event,char Partition,char Zone);`.  Would that be suitable for you?

Comment: @kaylum Yes, that worked! Thanks!

Comment: Make sure not to return a pointer to the stack

Comment: @ikegami I just created a buffer inside the function like this **char ContactID[12];** then at the end of the function i have a **return ContactID;**

Comment: If `char ContactID[12]` is found in the function (as opposed to being a global variable), you can't do that. That's undefined behaviour. The memory for `ContactID` becomes off limit when the function exits, so it's useless to return a pointer to it. You'll need to dynamically allocate memory (e.g. using `malloc`), receive a buffer from the caller, or use a global variable

Comment: Your "function prototype" is a syntax error, there cannot be `[12]` where it is

Comment: @ikegami: A more typical approach would be to use a `static`-qualified object.  Each call of the function will overwrite the previously-returned string, but using malloc in a microcontroller for something like this would generally add needless complexity.

Comment: @supercat, Re "*but using malloc in a microcontroller for something like*", That's why I said "receive a buffer from the caller". I also mentioned global var, which uses static storage, though yeah, you could also use a local static variable too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays can be returned as a pointer to the array element type. The returned pointer would be the address of the first element in the array (or memory region). In your case:

```
char *GetContactID(char Qual,long Event,char Partition,char Zone);
```

And to your comment:

> I just created a buffer inside the variable like this char ContactID[12]; then at the end of the function i have a return ContactID;

Be sure not to return stack addresses (e.g. local variable address). Such an address is only valid within the scope of the function and becomes an invalid (dangling) pointer if returned to the caller. Main options are:

1. Allocate dynamic memory in the function and return that as the function return value or in an output parameter. Caller is responsible for freeing the memory.
2. Caller passes in a memory address.
3. Use static memory.

The first two are the usual cases.

Update: I missed the fact that you are running on a microcontroller. In that case, static memory may be more appropriate as such systems tend not to want the overhead and complexity of dynamic allocations.